# Filter through these results?

Tags: php

Say I have the following text:

`["4294954874;Centhor 702L (1)","4294954873;Lightning DL904 (1)"]`

I want to return them in an array, for example:

```
$array = array('Centhor 702L', 'Lightning DL904');
```

What would be the best way to do this using PHP?

The stuff on the left and right of the info I need are randomly generated when I grab the response.

Comment: You could use regular expressions for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer structure will parse as JSON with `json_decode()`, resulting in an array that you can further extract from with a regular expression.

```
$s = '["4294954874;Centhor 702L (1)","4294954873;Lightning DL904 (1)","123876238547;Some Stuff (1500) (2)","4294961598;FXDWG Wide Glide (1584) (20)","4294954805;FXDWG Wide Glide (1690) (3)"]';
$arr = json_decode($s);
$output = array();

foreach ($arr as $part) {
  $matches = array();
  // Regex gets everything following the ;, but not ()
  preg_match('/;([A-za-z0-9.-() ]+)\s+\(\d+\)$/', $part, $matches);
  var_dump($matches[1]);

  // Add to an array...
  $output[] = trim($matches[1]);
}
```

#### Outputs

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "Centhor 702L"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "Lightning DL904"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "Some Stuff (1500)"
  [3]=>
  string(23) "FXDWG Wide Glide (1584)"
  [4]=>
  string(23) "FXDWG Wide Glide (1690)"
}
```

Don't forget to trim off the whitespace.

Why not just do the whole thing with a regular expression, you may ask?  Well, working inside the nested quotes is going to be a pain, and maybe you need other characters captured like `.,` which would also be problematic since they appear as separators too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it is working good apart from if there are hypens, for example: `"4294958716;DR-Z 250 (47)","4294967269;DR-Z125 (23)"` - It just returns them as `DR, DR`

Comment: @Latox Just add a hyphen inside the `[]` as in `[A-za-z0-9- ]`. It must be after the 0-9

Comment: Hi Michael, This worked great. Thank you. How would you suggest dealing with: `"4294961598;FXDWG Wide Glide (1584) (20)",
    "4294954805;FXDWG Wide Glide (1690) (3)",` - we want to keep what is in the first set of brackets there, eg (1584) and (1690) but strip out the other 2.

Comment: @Latox That makes it a good bit more complicated. See the edit I made above to the expression. I can't guarantee it will work in every case, but it worked for my test.

Comment: Hi Michael, this works fine! Thank you! You've been a great help. One more problem I've found (I think this is the last) - is dealing with periods in the data. EG: `Monster 400 S I.E` - how can we allow this in the regex? I suppose `;([A-za-z0-9-.() ]+)\s+\(\d+\)$` ?

Comment: @Latox Just add `.` inside the `[]` along with there the `-` was added.